# Git push confusion

Tags: git

I have branch named X which I want to push to a remote master branch.

But when I execute:

```
git fetch remote_name
git checkout -B branchX remote_name/master
...
Add a commit
...
git push remote_name master
```

I get an error saying:

```
Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes...
```

If i check my branchX unique commit value, then I can see that the checkout was correct and there have been added a new commit, so for sure i am a head of remote_name master.
And the remote master has NOT received any new commits in the meantime.

I normally use this procedure other places only difference here is that the branch names are not identical.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What does 'git status' say?

Comment: If your local change is in `branchX`, why did you push branch `master`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to push your local repo's `master` to your remote's `master`. Your push command effectively expands to this:

```
git push remote_name refs/heads/master:refs/heads/remote_name/master
```

Obviously, that's not what you're trying to do. You need to explicitly specify which branches go where:

```
git push remote_name branchX:master
```

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense. Had trouble understanding the docs :).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
git push remote_name branchX:master
```